# How can I change my regex to get a different set of images with WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: regex, perl, www-mechanize

I am making a web scraper for a website where I have to download images. I am currently using `WWW::Mechanize` and doing:

```
my @images=$mech->find_all_images(url_regex => qr/smallThumb/i);
```

which gives me all the images that have `smallThumb` in the URL.

How can I change `smallThumb` to `zoom` while retaining the previous links that have `smallThumb`?

Comment: Do you want to match URLs that contain both `smallThumb` *and* `zoom`? Or do you want to get two separate lists, one containing the `smallThumb` images and one containing the `zoom` images?

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
my @smallthumbs = $mech->find_all_images(url_regex => qr/smallThumb/i);
my @zooms       = $mech->find_all_images(url_regex => qr/zoom/i);
my @allimages = (@smallthumbs, @zooms);
```

The risk here is that you could have a URL that fits in both categories and get a dupe.

You can also go monkeying with the regex.

```
my @smallthumbs_or_zooms = $mech->find_all_images( url_regex => qr/smallThumb|zoom/i );
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for the reply . I was already doing the monkeying stuff but  the result is not the desired one. I want to retain urls with smallThumb and also the urls when I replace smallthumb with zoom using regex.Any help Guru.

Comment: i have my @smallthumbs={a.smallThumb.jpg , b.smallThumb.jpg} and I want my @smallandzoom={a.smallThumb.jpg , b.smallThumb.jpg,a.zoom.jpg , b.zoom.jpg}